# Angular 6 Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, primeng, ngfor

I think my problem is that the API delivers an Object instead of an array. So I need to modify the Object to be an Array?

How could this be done?
Object.assign?
Or Pipe?
Does anyone have a proper example?

I am still learning Angular this is my second Project so I need some help ;)

thy so far !

Here is my code

Getting data from API
..can't change the API it delivers an Object

**KnowledgeBaseService**

```
    import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
    import { WikiModel } from '../../models/wikiItems.model'
    import {catchError, map, take} from 'rxjs/operators';
    import {throwError} from 'rxjs';
    
    
    @Injectable()
    export class KnowledgeBaseService {
      wikiApiUrl: string = environment.wikiApiUrl;
      wikiList: WikiModel[] = [];
     constructor(
    
      protected http: HttpClient,) {}
    
        getwikiList() {
          return this.http.get(this.wikiApiUrl + "/list")
            .pipe(map((data: any[]) => {return this.wikiList = data;
                }), catchError(error => {
                return throwError('Its a Trap!')
              })
            );
        }
    }
```

subscribe to that Data

**KnowledgeBaseAdminComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { KnowledgeBaseService } from '../../../services/knowledge-base.service';
import { WikiModel } from '../../../../models/wikiItems.model';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {keyframes} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-knwoledge-center-admin',
  templateUrl: './knowledge-base-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./knowledge-base-admin.component.scss']
})
export class KnowledgeBaseAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  wikiList: WikiModel[] = [];
  displayDialog: boolean = false;
  editItem: WikiModel = null;

  constructor(private knowledgebaseService: KnowledgeBaseService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getwikiItems()
  }

  getwikiItems(): void {
    this.knowledgebaseService.getwikiList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.wikiList = data
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Wiki Items Geladen')
    );
    console.log(this.wikiList)
  }

  showDialogToAdd() {
    this.displayDialog = true;

  }  showDialogToEdit() {
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }
}
```

**WikiModel**

```
export class WikiModel {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  keyWords: string;

}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="section section-wiki-admin-head">
  <h1 class="h-centered">Begriffsdatenbank</h1>
</div>
<div class="section section-wiki-admin-table">
  <div class="wiki-articles-table-container">
    <p-table [value]="wikiList">
       <ng-template pTemplate="header">
         <tr>
           <th>Begriff</th>
           <th>Beschreibung</th>
           <th>Schlagworte</th>
         </tr>
       </ng-template>
       <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngFor="let wikiItems of wikiList">
         <tr>
           <td>{{wikiItems.title}}</td>
           <td>{{wikiItems.text}}</td>
           <td>{{wikiItems.keyWords}}</td>
         </tr>
       </ng-template>
     </p-table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section section-wiki-admin-footer">
  <div class="wiki-articles-table-toolbar">
    <button pButton id="wiki-a-new" class="ui-button-success wiki-a-footer-btn" type="button" icon="fa fa-plus" (click)="showDialogToAdd()" label="Neu"></button>
    <button pButton id="wiki-a-edit" class="ui-button-info wiki-a-footer-btn" type="button" icon="fa fa-edit"  (click)="showDialogToEdit()" label="Bearbeiten"></button>
    <button pButton class="ui-button-danger wiki-a-footer-btn"  type="button" icon="fa fa-trash" label="Löschen"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<p-dialog [header]="editItem && editItem? 'Bearbeiten' : 'Hinzufügen'" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" [width]="600">
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">

    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <div class="ui-g-4">
        <label for="wikiTitle">Titel</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-8">
        <input pInputText id="wikiTitle" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <div class="ui-g-4">
        <label for="wikiText">Wiki Text</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-8">
          <textarea id="wikiText" [rows]="5" [cols]="35" pInputTextarea ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- TODO: change  textfield to P-chips -->
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <div class="ui-g-4">
        <label for="wikikeywords">Schlagwörter</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-8">
        <input pInputText id="wikikeywords" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p-dialog>
```

**Error**

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

The Data from the API looks like:

```
{
  "error": null,
  "status": 200,
  "result": [
    {
      "_key": "338330",
      "_id": "knowbaseItems/338330",
      "_rev": "XIQvCoG--",
      "title": "Test Eintrag",
      "text": "Lalala",
      "keyWords": [
        "test"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_key": "341705",
      "_id": "knowbaseItems/341705",
      "_rev": "XIHSQhy--",
      "title": "Personalpronomen",
      "text": "Fahren Schlitten",
      "keyWords": [
        "ich",
        "du",
        "er"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "code": "200"
}
```

Comment: Please post all the template part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your service map operator must return **data.result**

```
getwikiList() {
 return this.http.get(this.wikiApiUrl + "/list")
            .pipe(map((data: any) => data.result ), 
                  catchError(error => { return throwError('Its a Trap!')})
            );
}
```

Just update p-table like this

```
<p-table  [value]="wikiList">
       <ng-template pTemplate="header">
         <tr>
           <th>Begriff</th>
           <th>Beschreibung</th>
           <th>Schlagworte</th>
         </tr>
       </ng-template>
       <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-wikiList>
         <tr>
           <td>{{wikiList.title}}</td>
           <td>{{wikiList.text}}</td>
           <td>{{wikiList.keyWords}}</td>
         </tr>
       </ng-template>
     </p-table>
```

[**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-service-data)

Comment: @HolzbeinWilli did you check the answer I have updated return the data.result

Comment: can you give me wikiApiUrl ?? @HolzbeinWilli

Comment: yep that erased that Error but my table is still empty.. ;/
my console Output looks like this now..

knowledge-base-admin.component.ts:34 
[]
length
:
0
__proto__
:
Array(0)
concat
:
ƒ concat()
constructor
:
ƒ Array()
copyWithin
:
ƒ copyWithin()
entries
:
ƒ entries()
every
:
ƒ every()
fill

Comment: its a local API..that GET data from an external ArangoDB Server

the API route looks like:
http://localhost:3100/knowledge-base/list

this URL gives a Full list of all Stored  Data..

Output like:
{"error":null,"status":200,"result":[{"_key":"341705","_id":"knowbaseItems/341705","_rev":"_XIHSQhy--_","title":"Personalpronomen","text":"Fahren Schlitten","keyWords":["ich","du","er"]}],"code":"200"}

Comment: @HolzbeinWilli I have update the answer hope I help here :) , check stackblitz example

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that Http is *asynchronous*. That means with this code:

```
  getwikiItems(): void {
    this.knowledgebaseService.getwikiList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.wikiList = data
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Wiki Items Geladen')
    );
    console.log(this.wikiList)  // <-- ALWAYS UNDEFINED!!
  }
```

The last console.log line will *always* be undefined.

The flow is as follows:

1) The getwikiList().subscribe is called.

2) The Http Get request is executed.

3) The getwikiList() method returns.

4) Your console.log is executed and the value is undefined at this point.

5) A response is received from the Get request.

6) The method defined within the subscribe method is notified and the data is provided and set to the this.wikilist.

So it is only after step 6 that you have the data.

If you want to see your values, you need to move your logging *within* the subscribe as shown below:

```
  getwikiItems(): void {
    this.knowledgebaseService.getwikiList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.wikiList = data;
        console.log(this.wikiList); // <-- here instead
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('Wiki Items Geladen')
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the below:

```
getwikiList() {
return this.http.get(this.wikiApiUrl + "/list")
        .pipe(map((data: any) => data.result || [];
            }), catchError(error => {
            return throwError('Its a Trap!')
          })
        );
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Look careful with your data coming from your api.
If you use model class only those elements define in model class access.so make your you add data.result and then pass into another object

For e.g
this.wikiList = data.result
In html
ngFor = "let wikilist of wikiList"